# Invalid Storyboard setting: Your app specifies the UIMainStoryBoardFile key for storyboard, when sending my app to the Apple Store

Tags: ios, xcode, application-loader

When i send my application to the App Store, i got this error:

[image]

My target is iOS 4.3 and later, am i obliged to target the iOS 5 as a minimum? is there any way to fix this without targeting the iOS 5 as minimum configuration requirements? thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Storyboards aren't supported in iOS < 5. Did you even test on 4 to check how your app performs? If not then you probably shouldn't be targeting it anyway.

Comment: I don't have iPhone yet :(, does it bother the user of the app to upgrade his iOS to the 5 version? i mean, would it be easy to upgrade it? is it free? please reply :)

Comment: You really shouldn't be releasing software for a device you've never tested on. Unfortunately the simulator is not good enough. You can quite easily write code that runs on the simulator but crashes on the device. iOS upgrades are free so a good percentage of users are on the latest version but some don't update.